# Application of Latin names for Taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy

The current taxonomy has family names like Canidae and Felidae. But Felidae has sub families like Felinae and Pantherinae. Roaring cats and non-roaring cats. My question is based on the fact that we can have common words for these families based in Latin: Felines, Canines, Pantherines. Can every family in the taxonomy be represented by this latter form? Is Pantherine a valid name? Is was created by dropping the a from the subfamily but caninine was created by dropping the da from the main family and replacing with in.

Answer (score 4):

Is "Pantherine" a valid vernacular name for this group in English? Sure, although "panther" is much clearer ("Pantherine" in English would mean "[like a panther](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pantherine)", not "a panther"). Also, many family names are fairly obscure: even a pretty well-known group, like [Apidae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apidae), would become "Apinine" in your scheme, which is less clear to me than "a family of bees".

Is it a valid family name? No. The International Code of Zoological Nomenclature (ICZN Code), which governs all scientific names for animals, says:

> [Article 29.2](http://www.nhm.ac.uk/hosted-sites/iczn/code/index.jsp?nfv=&article=29#2). **Suffixes for family-group names.** The suffix -OIDEA is used for a superfamily name, **-IDAE for a family name, -INAE for a subfamily name**, -INI for the name of a tribe, and -INA for the name of a subtribe. These suffixes must not be used at other family-group ranks. The suffixes of names for taxa at other ranks in the family-group are not regulated. [emphasis mine]

Family names that don't have an "-idae" suffix need to be corrected (ICZN Code [Article 32.5.3.1](http://www.nhm.ac.uk/hosted-sites/iczn/code/index.jsp?nfv=&article=32#5.3.1)).

Note that the ICZN Code doesn't cover other ranks in the family-group or above.

Comment: I think OP is getting at the fact that certain non-formal names are "valid" in English to refer to *members* of a group, hence: scarabaeid, coleopteran, neopteran, etc.

Comment: Yes I think the common English form are valid too. I would however like to know the correct forms for singular and plural in zoological and botanical names since comman names are not always obvious. I would assume all nouns there are in plural since they are talking about groups. And I assume the form is neutral. But I see words like Goniotrichum which is singular neutral so I wonder if I can change to Goniotricha ? Or is there some article I can read that would show how to convert all latin taxa names to common forms? like deuterostomia to deuterostomes.

Comment: And you say Apidae would become Apinine but in my system it would be Apeidos since wiktionary lists eidos as the singular form of idae.

Comment: *Goniotrichum* is a genus name, which are usually singular nouns -- a name like *Homo sapiens* means "[a] sapient [adjective] Human [noun]". IMO you would refer to "*Goniotrichum* species", rather than "Goniotrichums".